# Array of objects vs Object of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, oop

I have an object that represents the results of a calculation on a certain point on a map.

```
class Radiation
  attr_accessor :node
  attr_accessor :hash_of_results
  others....

  def initialize(node, sky, weather, etc.)
  ....
  end

  def calculations
   ......
  end
end
```

In my code I could have thousands of these objects. An alternative solution be

```
class Radiation
  attr_accessor :node
  attr_accessor :hash_of_results

  def initialize(*node, sky, weather, etc.)
  ....
  end

  def calculations
   ......
  end
end
```

In this case Radiation represents the whole field as I am passing an array of nodes and the other variables (sky, weather, etc.) are exactly the same.

My question is: which of the two approaches is better in terms of memory and performance? Are they equivalent? Maybe naively I tend to think that the second approach should be better because with the first solution I have to create many more instances of these objects.

Answer (score 2):

There's a famous saying by Donald Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Your problem isn't Ruby specific. It belongs to the territory of object modeling, rather than specific programming language. Therefore, if I were you, I would build a solid domain model first, implement some tasks at hand. Once this is done, one can move on to optimizations, should any problems arise. And I can tell you out of my experience, most of them you aren't anticipating now.

Speaking of design, I recommend you a wonderful classic book by Eric Evans unsurprisingly called "Domain-Driven Design".

Now something that's more specific to your question.

1. Creating less objects with lighter memory footprint will obviously save you some memory. Should you sacrifice design clarity for this? Doubt so.
2. For what I know about your problem, it appears to me that there should be a bit more classes. A good point to start is to take a look how actual process is happening in the field, extract nouns and verbs and go with them. For example, classes can be the following:

   - `RadiationMeasurement` – a radiation value at some point, a light-weight Struct
   - `EnvironmentalConditions` – what you named `sky`, `weather`, etc. goes here
   - `RadiationCondition` – an object that holds a value-object of `EnvironmentalConditions` and an array of `RadiationMeasurement` value-objects.

   I'm pretty sure this decomposition is an utter nonsense to you, since you know your area way better than I do, but it should provide a basic example of idea at a whole. What's good about this approach is most of the times it needs just a little bit of reasonable tweaking to be efficient from computational standpoint.

Hope this makes sense and helps at least a bit!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. And i agree that the problem is more general, but I thought that maybe that could be some specificity to Ruby. I am completely with you about not sacrificing good design. Actually I am rewriting the code almost rom scratch to make it more OO. This is why I have already started to consider issues related to performance. BTW, I bought the book you recommended. I have just finished Practical OO Design in Ruby and I am trying to apply the recommendations from the book.

Comment: I'm really glad my answer turned out useful! By the way, when it turns to profiling, the best (only?) way is just to set up an experiment in the exact environment your app is going to run in and do some measurements. E.g. what holds true for one Ruby implementation/version can be different for another, what works in MacOS X may fail to perform well in Windows etc.